# Comparing 2 columns in separate tables moving and moving only non duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join, where-clause

I am looking to compare a column in two seperate tables in MYSQL and then move the rows that arent present in the second table into it

for example:

Table 1:     Table 2:
id value     id value
1   6        1   6
2   7        2   7
3   8
4   9

i want to pull the 3 id's and values into table 2

i have been trying to do this with NOT LIKE however it will still pull duplicates through into the second table, i have also tried comparing the two id columns but that also didnt work by using the code

```
Select table1.* FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id != table2.id
```

it worked the first time i ran it however any more attempts and it would dump more and more results into table 2

im guessing i need to use an inner join however im not too sure how to go about it as i want the non matching results

current code i am using to move the table1 data to table2 is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (value1, value2,...) SELECT table1.value1, table1.value2,....
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id != table2.id
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: ID's in both tables are not just numerical, the id convention for these is XXX0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting values that are not in table two from table one

```
 INSERT INTO table2 (value1, value2,...) 
 SELECT table1.value1, table1.value2,....
 FROM table1
 WHERE table1.id NOT IN (
   SELECT table2.id FROM table2;
 );
```

Comment: this does not work, it is not pulling any rows from table 1 to table 2 still, my ID's are not all numerical, would i have to use NOT LIKE? or would this not work

Comment: ignore above fixed this issue by making sure the insert into from clause only had table 1 in it, thanks for the help